# Rails Minitest adds additional fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've got defined fixtures which has 2 examples

```
#test_results.yml
passed:
  answer: MyAnser
  scoring_point: 1
  test_result: passed
  user: registered

failed:
  answer: MyAnswer
  scoring_point: 1
  test_result: failed
  user: registered
```

Now I want to use it in my MiniTest by setup block

```
class TestResultsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    (...)
    @test_questions = test_questions(:failed)
  end
```

But instead of getting just one fixture (the :failed one) it loads two examples right away. I know I can explicitly create new record inside of setup block but I believe that's what fixtures are for.

Answer (score 0):

You to explicitly specify the fixture you intended as this `test_results(:failed)`
Your class should look like this:

```
class TestResultsControllerTest < ActiveSupport::IntegrationTest

    self.use_instantiated_fixtures = true

    setup do
    (...)
    @appropriateness_test_questions = @test_results['failed']
end
```

You can learn more [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html).

Comment: No, I accidentally misnamed the variables. It should be `@test_questions = test_questions(:failed)` instead of `@appropriateness_test_questions = appropriateness_test_questions(:failed)`. Question updated.

Comment: If I do `@test_questions = test_questions(test_questions(:failed))` I'm getting an error: `StandardError: No fixture named '#<TestResult:0x00007fe82756e840>' found for fixture set 'test_results'`

Comment: please take note of `ActiveSupport::IntegrationTest` derivation. Derive from `ActiveSupport` not `ActionDispatch`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue since ActionDispatch comes from scaffold. When I change it to `ActiveSupport` I'm getting `uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::IntegrationTest (NameError)`

Comment: ok do this `self.use_instantiated_fixtures = true` then go ahead and replace your test to `@appropriateness_test_questions = @test_results['failed']` I've edited my answer

Comment: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer` if I change to @test_results[0] it will load... first example from `test_result.yml`... twice!! If I pass `@test_results[1]` this give me first example and... `[]` as a second.